# Trying to remove "non-parentheses" characters in python won't work. I'm using the remove method and a For loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm working on a little coding exercise. But I can't seem to strip a string of Non-parentheses characters.

here's the code:

```
def valid_parentheses(string):
    lis = list(string)
    print(lis)
    stack = []
    for i in lis:
        if i != '(' and i != ')':
            lis.remove(i)
    print(lis)
```

I pass in 'hi(hi)()'
but it prints an output of

```
['h', 'i', '(', 'h', 'i', ')', '(', ')']
['i', '(', 'i', ')', '(', ')']
```

it's weird because it removes the 'h' characters, but not the 'i' charactaters. I mostly want to know what's going on here. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a list you are iterating is like sawing the branch you are sitting on. Python iterates a list by indices. On index 0, you remove the 0th element (`"h"`). Now `"i"` is the 0th element, but Python won't have another iteration with index 0, it goes to index 1 in the next iteration, and `"i"` is never looked at.

The best way to do this specifically is using `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'[^()]', '', 'hi(hi)()')
```

If you want a more general solution, then filtering elements is better done with `filter` function, or equivalently and more Pythonically, with a conditional comprehension:

```
''.join(c for c in 'hi(hi)()' if c == '(' or c == ')')
```

If you have to use a loop and remove elements, then loop in reverse. This is like sitting at the other side of the saw, the side that doesn't fall down. When you remove an element, you don't change an index of any element you are yet to iterate over.

EDIT: And as you realised in the comment, it is much easier to just build a new data structure, which completely avoids the problem of modifying the structure you're iterating on. This is actually what both regex and comprehension solutions above are doing.

Comment: okay. Sorry for the noob question. So, I should just append the parentheses to a new list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is, you a modifying the list you are iterating over.

This should work:

```
def valid_parentheses(string):
for i in string:
    if i != '(' and i != ')':
        string = string.replace(i,'')
print(string)
```